# How to create placeholders for xml file with jaxb?

Tags: java, testing, jaxb

There is integration tests. 
I need to compare response from controller with content of xml-file from resouses;
Xml file like this:

```
<User>
  <name>Tania</name>
  <surname>Ivanova</surname>
</User>
```

Read file using this method:

```
private Object readFromFile(String fileName) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    File file = new File(getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile());

    return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
}
```

Can I use only one file with placeholders in name and surname tags instead creation xml file for every test?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. How would you want to use those placeholders? If you're unmarshalling the XMLs why don't you just compare the POJOs? From your question I assume you're not interested in the actual data but only whether elements exist etc. - that could be done by validating the xml with some xsd schema.

Comment: @Thomas  I mean, that there is serialization before creating pojo from xml file (extra step), I need just recieve xml from server and compare with xml file, may be in String format.